# Display the Request dialog and then redirect

Tags: facebook, redirect, dialog

I'm displaying the requests dialog multi with JS SDK when the user clicks the login with Facebook button on my site. Now I want to redirect the user after he/she sends the invite or cancels the request dialog so I can then proceed to signing him or her in the site.

```
button = document.getElementById('fbc-login-button');
    button.onclick = function() {

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(response.authResponse.accessToken);
            }
            else {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(response.authResponse.accessToken);
                    }}, {scope: 'email'});
            }

        });

    };

    function sendUserToLoginProcess(accessToken){
        var fb_signin_url = '<?php echo CustomLocal_Resource_Url_Process::userSignin() ?>?command=<?php echo CustomLocal_Logic_Customer_User::COMMAND_FB_SIGNIN ?>&url_redirect=<?php echo Custom_Resource_Url_Customer::main(); ?>&url_redirect_fail=<?php echo Custom_Resource_Url_Customer::signin(); ?>';
        this.location = fb_signin_url + '&token=' +  accessToken;
    };

    function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(accessToken) {
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'My Great Request'
        }, sendUserToLoginProcess(accessToken));
    }
```

Comment: And your actual _question_ is …?

Comment: haha sorry, As I was saying I want to redirect. So in the code there's a callback sendUserToLoginProcess function. But this one redirects simultaneously as the request dialog is loaded on the page. So the user then doesn't get the chance to invite his/her friends because he/she is being redirected. I want the redirection to happen after the the user is finish with the request dialog or press the cancel on the dialog. How should I go about that?

Comment: Your problem with the above code is/was, that you are not using `sendUserToLoginProcess` as a callback function, but executing it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i think manage to get it with this code:

```
    button = document.getElementById('fbc-login-button');
    button.onclick = function() {

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(response.authResponse.accessToken);
            }
            else {
                FB.login(function(response) {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                        sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(response.authResponse.accessToken);
                    }}, {scope: 'email'});
            }

        });

    };

    function sendUserToLoginProcess(accessToken){
        var fb_signin_url = '<?php echo CustomLocal_Resource_Url_Process::userSignin() ?>?command=<?php echo CustomLocal_Logic_Customer_User::COMMAND_FB_SIGNIN ?>&url_redirect=<?php echo Custom_Resource_Url_Customer::main(); ?>&url_redirect_fail=<?php echo Custom_Resource_Url_Customer::signin(); ?>';
        this.location = fb_signin_url + '&token=' +  accessToken;
    };

    function sendRequestViaMultiFriendSelector(accessToken) {
        FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'Shop with me!'
        }, 
        function(response)
        {
            sendUserToLoginProcess(accessToken)
        });
    }
```

I used the callback function(response) to trigger the sendUserToLoginProcess() which then proceeds to redirect and signin the user. But I'm not really using the response variable so I hope that's just ok.